# Tensor Slicing and applying function over tensor

Tags: tensorflow

I have two questions:

1. Let tensor `T` has shape `[n1, n2, n3, n4]`. Let another tensor `IDX` with shape `[n1, n2]` of type `int` contains desired indices. How can I obtain tensor of shape `[n1, n2, n4]` where I want to extract only those indices from `n3` dim of `T`, which specified in `IDX`. Simple example:

   ```
   x = [[[2, 3, 1, 2, 5],
      [7, 1, 5, 6, 0],
      [7, 8, 1, 3, 8]],
     [[0, 7, 7, 6, 9],
      [5, 6, 7, 8, 8],
      [2, 3, 2, 9, 6]]]
   idx = [[1, 0, 2],
      [4, 3, 3]]
   res = [[3, 7, 1],
      [9, 8, 9]]`
   ```

   2. Given a function which takes 1D tensors func(x, y) how can I apply it to 4D tensors X, Y over the last dimension, i.e. result -- 3D tensor with result [i, j, k] =  f(X[i, j, k, :], Y[i, j, k, :]) for all i, j, k. I found tf.py_func but can't get how to use it in my case.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I worked question 1 out with `tf.gather_nd`.

The inputs are:

- `x`: your tensor `T` from which to extract values, of shape `[n1, n2, n3, n4]`

  - I used clearer values from 0 to `size(T)`
- `idx`: the indices you want to extract from `T`, of shape `[n1, n2]` and containing values from `0` to `n3 - 1`

The result is:

- `res`: the extracted values of `T` for each indice in `idx`, of shape `[n1, n2, n4]`

---

As `tf.gather_nd()` expect you to create the whole indices to retrieve in `x` (for instance `[1, 0, 4, 1]`), we have to create it first in `indices_base`.

The argument `indices` needs to be of shape `res + R` i.e. `[n1, n2, n4, R]` where `R=4` is the rank of the Tensor `x`.

```py
# Inputs:
n1 = 2
n2 = 3
n3 = 5
n4 = 2
x = tf.reshape(tf.range(n1*n2*n3*n4), [n1, n2, n3, n4])  # range(60) reshaped
idx = tf.constant([[1, 0, 2], [4, 3, 3]])  # shape [n1, n2]

range_n1 = tf.reshape(tf.range(n1), [n1, 1, 1, 1])
indices_base_1 = tf.tile(range_n1, [1, n2, n4, 1]) 

range_n2 = tf.reshape(tf.range(n2), [1, n2, 1, 1])
indices_base_2 = tf.tile(range_n2, [n1, 1, n4, 1])

range_n4 = tf.reshape(tf.range(n4), [1, 1, n4, 1])
indices_base_4 = tf.tile(range_n4, [n1, n2, 1, 1])

idx = tf.reshape(idx, [n1, n2, 1, 1])
idx = tf.tile(idx, [1, 1, n4, 1])

# Create the big indices needed of shape [n1, n2, n3, n4]
indices = tf.concat(3, [indices_base_1, indices_base_2, idx, indices_base_4])

# Finally we can apply tf.gather_nd
res = tf.gather_nd(x, indices)
```

---

Anyway, this is quite complicated and I am not sure if it can produce good performance.

P.S: you should post question 2 in a separate post.